# Wordpress foreach error

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I'm trying to basically access a row in a database from wordpress and for each row perform a function.

here is the php:

```
<?php
require('../../wp-blog-header.php');
global $wpdb;

$feed = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_aggreg_emails");   
    foreach($feed as $row) {
        echo $row['email'];
    }

?>
```

How ever I keep getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in 
                   /home/wp-content/email/index.php on line 6
```

A mate has tried to recreate it but he can't :/

Please can someone spread some light to this situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you've posted does not contain a syntax error. Please post the code that contains the error.

Comment: THAT IS the code.... that is the problem.

Comment: What is the name and path of the file with your quoted PHP code in? Is it the same one as mentioned in the error message? (just double-checking)

Comment: yup it is. its ok double checking is good :)

Comment: What happens if you comment out the whole foreach section and put print_r($feed); in its place?

Comment: it prints out: stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [email] => mail@mail.com [user_name] => username1 )

Comment: I'm not sure that the problem was, but I changed

     $wpdb->get_row()
to: 
            

     $wpdb->get_results()

and all seems to be working now :)

thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
$feed = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_aggreg_emails");
```

to

```
$feed = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_aggreg_emails");
```

using get_row is expecting to return 1 row, but you are trying to select everything from that table, so using get_results will populate the array you need for your for loop

then in your foreach

```
foreach($feed as $row){
   echo $row->email;
}
```